# typescript - access to object properties through indexer - obj[key]

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

i need to access to an object property using a string as key

```
interface MyObject {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string;
  prop4: string;
  prop5: string;
} 

let initialValues: MyObject;

//i set some property
initialValues = {
    prop1: 'xxxx'
    prop2: 'yyyy'
}

//i set some other (existing) property 
[3,4,5,6].map(i => {
    initialValues[`prop${i}`] = 'zzzz';
});
```

i got this error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'MyObject'
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has assumed widest possible type for `[3,4,5,6]` as `string[]`. Add `as const` to narrow it.

```
([3,4,5] as const).map(i => {
initialValues[`prop${i}`] = 'zzzz';});
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZZABygHtqBGALmQGcwpQBzAbgqq0GAJlYcuIPgJr1qAZgD8Yzj36UZDACxL2KyWsGyArDvGqKAX2QUKAelvJg7CETZ0AtiiHVoYdBQAbF0cQYDBgOACANUiAVwg2VgwcfEJkAF4SaUMGFmQAcgAPYsL8gBpsjWpRAvQ69HLLNTtbJzZgt09kOjAAC2hkAAoIQuAOHgBKKt90a3JBgG05Ms0yowBdZDg2ZAQ6EA4JgDp3OGpBp3SAPiz1KlAwiOi4hIWAA28AEmJgCzfNzL5ABeIKB%20TUFgmvCAA)

Comment: this only works because you changed the OP's input type: i.e. you make prop3 to 5 optional

Comment: @TmTron of course they must be optional! How else you can initialize object of type `MyObject` with partial data? But only making them optional doesn't resolve the question posed. Provided code has many errors and typos, but question is about last statement with array of object keys. I think.

Comment: You can initialize partial data by using an `init()` function with type `Partial<MyObject>` without changing the interface type as explained in my answer.
However, you are right, that the question is not very clear and could be interpreted either way.

Comment: @TmTron of course you can fool the transpiler and initialize variable with any data using `any` type that actually turns off type protection downgrading Typescript to plain javascript. But if the interface says all properties are non-nullable, then they must be initialized on creation! That the whole idea of type protection.

Answer (score -1):

Typescript will not be able to understand that your values will be valid key of the interface. It is a limitation.

Best you can do is use `type assertion`, but do not that it does not provide type safety instead you are telling TS that the type is correct :

```
interface MyObject {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3?: string;
  prop4?: string;
  prop5?: string;
} 

let initialValues: MyObject = {
  prop1: 'x',
  prop2: 'y'
}

let ans = [3,4,5,6].map(i => {
    initialValues[`prop${i}` as keyof MyObject] = 'zzzz';
});
```

Notice TS cannot figure out that `6` will not be a problem here.

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChlkAHKAe0oEYAuZAZzClAHMBucq2ygCZmbDiB59qdAMwB+Eey68KUygBZ5rReOX86AVk2ilpAL7JSpADYQioYGGBwrANWcBXCC2YYc+QsgAvCSSAkzIAOQAHhEANKF0wpHoEWaWNkRwICxByADa0rFqsfoAugB0ALZwlAAUwEEAfCEUFPaOzm5Wnix5AAaqACTEwKZ9yHA5ANYQ6DQwaFh4BGCluREAXlsbEbymAJTcQA)

Comment: you changed the OP's input type: i.e. you made prop3 to 5 optional

Answer (score -1):

Use a type assertion to tell TypeScript that this **will** be a property of the object:

```js
interface MyObject {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: string;
  prop4: string;
  prop5: string;
} 

let initialValues: MyObject;

//i set some property
initialValues = {
    prop1: 'xxxx'
    prop2: 'yyyy'
}

//i set some other (existing) property 
[3,4,5,6].map(i => {
    initialValues[`prop${i}` as keyof MyObject] = 'zzzz';
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZZABygHtqBGALmQGcwpQBzAbgqq0GAJlYcuIPgJr1qAZjGce-SjIYAWRRKmqh1AKxblFAL7IKFADYQioYGGBxLANScBXCG1YYc+QiooAekDgdht2OgBbFD1oMHQKOwcnV0sPNmQAXhJpQVkWZAByAA9S4sKAGly1alEi9Ab0QtMA8mDQtnC2KJQ6MAALaGQACghi4A4eAEoauPRzcgBtOQr1Cv0KgDYAXQA6SLhqYdDMgD4c1Sokxxd3T0WAAz0AEmJgEwfkOAyAawh0OgwNBYPAEMDbLJFABeMKhhRUJimvCAA)

However, be careful when you do this! TypeScript won't check that the property is a valid property of the object, so you lose complete runtime type safety. You can see that in this case TypeScript doesn't complain.

Alternatively, if you know which values will be in the array, you can tell TypeScript that, and it will be able to recognize valid keys:

```js
interface MyObject {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3?: string;
  prop4?: string;
  prop5?: string;
} 

let initialValues: MyObject;

//i set some property
initialValues = {
    prop1: 'xxxx',
    prop2: 'yyyy'
};

//i set some other (existing) property 
let values: (3 | 4 | 5 | 6)[] = [3, 4, 5, 6];
values.map(i => {
    initialValues[`prop${i}`] = 'zzzz';
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZZABygHtqBGALmQGcwpQBzAbgqq0GAJlYcuIPgJr1qAZgD8Yzj36UZDACxL2KyWsGyArDvGqKAX2QUKAGwhFQwMMDi2Aam4CuENqww4+IRqFAD0ocDsDux0ALYoQtTQYOgUTi5unrY+bMgAvCTShgwsyADkAB5VFWUANEUa1KLl6K3oZZYh5OGRbNFscSh0YAAW0MgAFBAVwBw8AJSNyejW5PZEAG7evqwTcsgAPsiah8hGpwBs8wDaALr5yNdytccvRi8Xt2pb2b4AdLE4NQJpE8gA+QrqKjpVwebZsa4AA0SABJiMALIj7gUygAvfG4spqCzzXhAA)

You can see that in this case, TypeScript only complains about `prop6`. This is the preferred solution if you can do it, because we keep type safety.